# RESTKIT : deserialize JSON with not all relationship attribute

Tags: ios, json, swift, restkit

I tried to deserialize a JSON  like this :

```
{"id":1234, "content": "Hi, This is a message", "dateSaved":"10/04/2015 11:00", "user":{"id":12}}
```

Model :

```
class Message: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var content: String
    @NSManaged var dateSaved: NSDate
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var user: User
}

class User: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var id: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var login: String
    @NSManaged var mobile: String
    @NSManaged var password: String
    @NSManaged var picture: NSData
    @NSManaged var messages: NSSet
}
```

The User is already saved in iOS data base, so i don't need to send all its data from the server. The problem is that both `RKRelationshipMapping` and `RKConnectionDescription` seem not to be done for this kind of works : the first works for complete objects, that can be directly operate by CoreData ; the second one can only be used with identifier and not object

I can not change the way that the server serialize objects to JSON, because an other Android app works with this kind of JSON

Somebody knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Show your code and model and explain what about the mapping doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I have just forgotten to set the method `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary` for the `RKRelationshipMapping` :

```
let messageAttributesMapping = [
    "id":  "id",
    "content":  "content",
    "dateSaved":  "dateSaved"
]

extension Message {
    class func mappingResponse(managedObjectStore: RKManagedObjectStore) -> RKMapping {
        let messageMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Message", inManagedObjectStore: managedObjectStore)

        messageMapping.identificationAttributes = ["id"]
        messageMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(messageAttributesMapping)

        let userMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "User", inManagedObjectStore: managedObjectStore)
        userMapping.identificationAttributes = ["id"]
        userMapping.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary(["id" : "id"])

        messageMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKRelationshipMapping(fromKeyPath: "user", toKeyPath: "user", withMapping: userMapping))

        return messageMapping
    }
}
```

This solution works to deserialize a JSON, but i am still wondering if i should try to use a `RKConnectionDescription`, that seemed to be built for relationship where we have just id?